# Centering header horizontally compared to centering rest of page vertically

Tags: html, css

For the life of me I can't figure out why one of my pages (that has the most amount of content) is shifting my header.

[Here](http://www.denniscliment.com/AppMap/applist.html) is page header shifted a bit compared to [here](http://www.dennisclimetn.com/appMap/about.html).

I get that I has more content and is thus pushing things beyond the fold but if my header is set to an absolute position then why would it be effected by the content area below it.

i created a more simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bardsworth/vLJGt/1/) link to help make this easier to read through

If you change the min-height of the #mainContent line 72 to anything small enough to fit in the fold you will see that the position of the header changes. I have some content that gets centered on the screen pending how large the browser is and then for pages that are too large the mainContent should sit flush top with the header.

```
#mainContent {

width:900px;
min-height:800px;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
overflow: auto;

text-align: center;

padding-bottom:20px;
```

}

Comment: Please, replace the offsite links with images of the relevant portions of the sites, and we will be better able to help you.

Comment: smell like virus.. Just give ur code or html editor link

Comment: @user1956570 a virus? :D This is not the proper way of centering things. I would recommend you to use a wrapper and add `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: I added a link to a more simplified version. where if you change the min-height you will see the shift of the header.